# 500 error but no info about the link GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 "-"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, error-log, access-log

I am getting the following 500 in my access logs in rare occasions

```
IP - - [05/Nov/2013:14:44:52 -0600] "-GET / HTTP/1.1" 500  "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
IP - - [05/Nov/2013:14:44:52 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

However I cant see what page is throwing it so I was wondering how can I go about troubleshooting and find the page.

Thanks

Comment: The logs indicate that the root document is throwing the 500, hence the "GET /".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page that's throwing it is "/". So you want to look at what your index file is in your document root (`index.php` for example). Additionally, make sure that the log is for a **site** that you have setup correctly (e.g. not default vhost).

If you have multiple vhosts, you may want to create a custom log file for each vhost so you know which one it is that is returning a 500 error. It would be the directives: `TransferLog` and `ErrorLog`.